# Webpack not recognize jsx only from package module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a package that exports react components.

When I install the package and a component, and run site I am getting an error from webpack:

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (84:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,

This error refers to a line containing a jsx element.

When I copied the component, and imported it worked ok.

This is my webpack.config.js (no .babelrc file, I also tried with .bablerc file):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        }            
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer? What is the outcome?

Comment: It seems to solve it technically, I voted, but it is not visible since I have no rank myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try indicating `libraryTarget` in output.

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },
```

`libraryTarget` specifies how your component will be exported. Refer to the docs for details: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue, can you explain a little the issue and the solution?

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it out. @cardinaro